# Functional index in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I have Companies vertices in my OrientDB with property Name which represents the name of the company.

I need to search data in those vertices by property Name by paticular algorithm. For example, I have to convert all symbols to low case, remove all spaces and remove some special simbols.

In Postgresql I would be create functional index with function which implements this algorithm. But the problem is that speed of such functinal index didn't satisfy me (in table with 20 mln records search record by this index takes about 1 sec).

How can I implement such algorithm in OrientDB and how eficiently it would?

Answer (score 1):

To remove spaces try this JS function:

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var c=g.command('sql','select from Companies');
var b=g.command("sql","select Name.indexOf(' ') from Companies");
var no_space=[];

for(i=0;i<c.length;i++)
{
  if(b[i].getProperty("Name")>-1)
  {
    var company=c[i].getProperty("Name").substring(0,b[i].getProperty("Name"));
    company+=c[i].getProperty("Name").substring(b[i].getProperty("Name")+1,c[i].length);
    no_space.push(company);
  }
}

return no_space;
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Hi Michela! Maybe I misunderstood you but you suggest me remove spaces from Name property permanently. But it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi @Alex my function doesn't remove the spaces permanently because if I do a select into my DB I don't see any changes.

Comment: Pls make me a bit clear hiow I can use your function? Pls give me an example of query with your function. And one more point. I have a 20+ millions records in my vertex class. How efficient this function would with such amount of data? Thanks/

Comment: Hi @Alex, about @Michela Bonizzi's function, it retrieves the company names modified to lower case and without spaces but the changes are on the fly, not permanent (the output shown is temporary because it's a simple `SELECT`). If you launch a new `SELECT FROM Companies` you'll see that the dataset hasn't changed. I used its logic to create a new function that allows to compare an input parameter (lower case and without spaces) with this modified list to get the results you're looking for. Hope to have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used this simple dataset to try your case:

```
CREATE CLASS Companies EXTENDS V

CREATE PROPERTY Companies.Name STRING

CREATE INDEX Companies.Name ON Companies(Name) NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX

CREATE VERTEX Companies SET Name = 'Company 1'
CREATE VERTEX Companies SET Name = 'Company 2'
CREATE VERTEX Companies SET Name = 'Company 3'
CREATE VERTEX Companies SET Name = 'Company 4'
CREATE VERTEX Companies SET Name = 'Company 5'
CREATE VERTEX Companies SET Name = 'Company 6'
```

**1.** Searching vertices by a defined algorithm:

To retrieve the results you're looking for, you can implement a query by using [OrientSQL methods](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Methods.html) like `.toLowerCase()` and `LIKE` operator. E.g.:

```
    SELECT Name FROM Companies WHERE Name.toLowerCase() LIKE 'comp%1'

    ----+------+---------
    #   |@CLASS|Name
    ----+------+---------
    0   |null  |Company 1
    ----+------+---------
```

You can also create a function containing your query:

[image]

**2.** About the index choice, an `HASH_INDEX` (I used a `NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX`) would be better because it is more practical on large numbers (like in your case) and it has many advantages as explained [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Indexes.html)

**EDITED**

I created this function to give an example (`inputName` parameter is the company `Name` you're looking for):

[image]

Once the function has been created, you can call it by using the OSQL:

**STUDIO:**

[image]

**CONSOLE:**

```
SELECT EXPAND(myFunction3('company1'))

----+-----+---------+---------
#   |@RID |@CLASS   |Name
----+-----+---------+---------
0   |#12:0|Companies|Company 1
----+-----+---------+---------

1 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.015 sec(s).
```

About the performance, I don't know the complexity of your dataset (e.g. number and type of the fields) and it's hard to say. You could test and use these examples as a starting point to create many and more complex customized functions.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I have to create more sophisticated algorithm for searching (not only convert to lowerCase, but also remove spaces and some special symbols and phrases). Can I do such things?

Comment: Hi @Lucas, thank you, but the problem is that I have big enough amount of records in class Companies (about 21+ millions).
The query (select from Companies) doesn't work for me because of out of memory error ("java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space") and it's expected.
This case I asked, can I add functional index or somethins similar on my class Companies in order to search in it by my algorithm (making lowcase and removing spaces) quick enough?

Comment: @AlexZhulin I don't think you can do what you are asking for with the indexes.
You can increase the memory that you assigning to Orient.
You can use a javascript function that removes all spaces from the name, all special symbols and convert all symbols to low case and then do the search.

Comment: @AlessandroRota can you estimate my scenario for my task? 
1. I'll add extra property to my class (NormalizedName). 
2. Somehow I'll fill that property in records of my class. 
3. On insert or update operation I'll add hook which will fill or update property NormalizedName. 
What do you think? Is it good scenario or exists something better?